# How to extract a specific instance with regex?

Tags: regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract a specific instance of a value in a javascript/xhr request. Via this [link](https://unsplash.com/napi/photos/u8TI0LMLUWw) I am trying to extract the 1st instance of the created_at value but it keeps returning all matches which is 7 instances. I just need the first one:

```
\\"created_at.":(.*?),
```

Comment: If you are using the global flag `/g` you could omit it.

Comment: why you wanna use regex when it's clean JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

Just load it as JSON and get `'created_at'` value.

```py
import json
json.loads(response.body)['created_at']
```